# Where does Screensaver store images?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, filesystem, screensaver

I have only used iPhoto a couple of times by accident (preferring one of the many alternatives).  Each time, I carefully removed those images from iPhoto to the iPhoto trashcan and then emptied the iPhoto trash. Consequently, all the iPhoto sections appear empty:

[image]

But when I look at the screensaver, pictures show up when one of the iPhoto directories is selected (the directories can't be deleted in any way I know).

[image]

I'm assuming that the images were copied into a screensaver cache (or maybe a link was created). **Where are these screen saver images stored?**

BTW, I'm still running Snow Leopard on a beautiful 4gig iMac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrounging around in plist files (thank you `find` and `grep`!), I found the beginnings of an answer, but I'm still a little confused.

It seems that those pesky images have been lingering around (renamed, of course) in the following directory:
`~/Pictures/`

Deleted them, and now when selecting any of the iPhoto portions of Screensaver, I get the appropriate error message:
[image: The selected source contains no pictures. Please choose a new source...]

-Yeah, that's the ticket!

I hope others will have more details, so I'll wait a couple of days before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question remains oddly unanswered. My best guess is the iPod Photo Cache (in iPhoto, Aperture packages) ... but then it needs something different for Photos.app.

Comment: The question **was** self-answered and he just didn't mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: My answer is essentially a guess, so I didn't think it deserved a check.  But since no one has come along and picked up some easy points, I'll go ahead and check my answer.  I'll happily change the accepted answer if someone comes along and explains things [hint hint].